# how partition for OpenSuSE dual-boot

Tags: partition, system-installation, swap

Currently I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 and have quite a bit of free space on this disc:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1f3b4b3e

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1       927944704 976771071  48826368 23.3G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2  *    732633088 927944703 195311616 93.1G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
thufir@doge:~$
```

What partition scheme would make sense for installing OpenSuSE onto the free space?  I'm not sure, as I go through the OpenSuSE install process, how I'd use `sda1` as the swap.  What settings should I set for `sda3` for OpenSuSE?  Make the mount point `/` and mark as bootable?  Not sure how do do that during the install process.

Comment: I'd suggest you double the suggested size of the **/boot** partition, as the default is barely large enough for 3 kernel images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenSuSE install can help you do this by resizing and creating your partitions for you. It should automatically use your swap partition. If not then you'll go to advanced partition settings when installing and have the swap partition be mounted to swap.

However, if you want to free do this by hand (I would **not** recommend it).

- First umount the /dev/sda2
- Next run fsck on /dev/sda2 (you really don't want any errors)
- Third, use resize2fs.
- In fsck, delete the old partition and create two new ones and toggle the boot flag where needed.
- Finally, ave grub update itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're booting with windows 8 make some unallocated space for SUSE when booting SUSE it will automatically choose the swap partition and primary partition (only in SUSE 12.0 + )