# What is a suitable dual boot partitioning scheme (Debian and openSUSE Leap)

Tags: debian, partition, opensuse

I have been a Debian user since several years but now would like to try openSUSE as well in a dual boot environment. Here are some thoughts:

- Two root partitions.To avoid the two installations from stepping on each other I am thinking of keeping two root partitions of 50 GB each.
- Two home partitions, again about 50 GB each. Since application releases from the two distros are going to be different (KDE 4 versus 5) it makes sense to have separate home directories. I don't know if all applications from the two distros are compatible with one another. I would like to be cautious than sorry.
- One big user data partition. My concern is more around user data, which in a single boot setup resides in the `/home` directory. It seems eminent that a separate partition has to be created. However, it would be convenient if my personal data that is not affected by KDE release continues to remains accessible from `/home`. Say the mount-point for the data partition is `/mnt/data`, then I would create symlinks like `my-docs` in both the home directories. This scheme has the obvious problem of creating a symlink every time I wanted to work in a new directory in the `/home` directory.

Any ideas from the good folks here will be appreciated.

EDIT: The [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182572/how-partition-for-opensuse-dual-boot) issue clearly does not answer the question here. There are plenty of resources available on how-to-partition and how-to-dual boot. The query here is on the partitioning scheme (number of partitions, their size, role) given some specific ideas. The quick marking as duplicate is giving an impression that the question has not been properly read.

Comment: Marking as duplicate is what the majority vote is. If it weren't for that this should be closed as either too broad or generating opinionated.

Answer (score -1):

- One `efi partition` of at least `1MB` size with `grub efi` installed, which points to `/boot/grub` of the `debian` or `openSUSE` partition.